# Sum fields inside json array in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE stackoverflow_question (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    json_ob mediumtext default null,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I do some inserts:

```
insert into stackoverflow_question values(null, 'albert', '[{name: "albert1", qt: 2},{name: "albert2", qt: 2}]');
insert into stackoverflow_question values(null, 'barbara', '[{name: "barbara1", qt: 4},{name: "barbara2", qt: 7}]');
insert into stackoverflow_question values(null, 'paul', '[{name: "paul1", qt: 9},{name: "paul2", qt: 11}]');
```

Eventually, I will need to sort this table by total quantity.
in the examples above, "paul" has quantity = 20, while "barbara" has quantity = 11. And "albert" has quantity = 4.

Is it possible to create a select statement where a new field is created on the fly? Something like this:

```
SELECT
SUM (loop json_ob and sum all the quantity fields) AS total_quantity,
id,
name
FROM
stackoverflow_question
ORDER BY total_quantity
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `json_ob` is actually a valid json object then you can use [`JSON_TABLE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html#function_json-table) to extract the quantities and aggregate:

```
SELECT s.*, SUM(t.qt) total_quantity 
FROM stackoverflow_question s, 
     JSON_TABLE(json_ob, '$[*]' COLUMNS (qt INTEGER PATH '$.qt')) t
GROUP BY s.id
ORDER BY total_quantity DESC;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9vsDKdCnwu6xhEBhrerhtF/1).

Comment: This works. However, I realized that current mysql version in use is 5.*. Is there a solution for older versions?

Comment: @oderfla no, there is no equivalent to json_table() for MySql 5.*. Maybe you can try the answers in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67737833/error-when-calling-json-table-in-mysql-5-7-compatible-amazon-aurora

Answer (score 2):

According to [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/) your JSON is not valid.

That's why this SQL returns an error (`ERROR 3141 (22032): Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function json_table: "Missing a name for object member." at position 2.")`

```
SELECT 
   j.name, j.qt
FROM JSON_TABLE('[{name: "paul1", qt: 9},{name: "paul2", qt: 11}]',
          "$[*]" COLUMNS (name varchar(20) PATH "$.name", qt int PATH "$.qt")) j ;
```

and this will return the values:

```
SELECT 
   j.name, j.qt
FROM JSON_TABLE('[{"name": "paul1", "qt": 9},{"name": "paul2", "qt": 11}]',
          "$[*]" COLUMNS (name varchar(20) PATH "$.name", qt int PATH "$.qt")) j ;
```

output:

| name | qt |
| --- | --- |
| paul1 | 9 |
| paul2 | 11 |

You can convert your relaxedJSON, to JSON, using tools like : [www.relaxedjson.org](http://www.relaxedjson.org/docs/converter.html?source=%7Bone%20%3A%20%271%3A1%27%20two%20%3A%20%7B%20three%3A%20%273%3A3%27%20%7D%7D)